# Why doesn't my tab pane initialise in IE7? jQuery Tools Tab issue in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, tabs

This page works as needed in IE8+, FF, Safari etc. Only IE7 exhibits the problems. Does anyone know why?

[Here is the problem page](http://acodesign.co.uk/enter/staging/bf_html_master/)

First issue is that the page content doesn't show below the tabs on page load, fine in all other browser - in IE7 it's necessary to click the first tab item to make the content appear.

Secondly, If you click a tab at the top and then click the help button the right of the tab headers, a help section expands down. On every other browser, it expends down and pushes the content below down as expected. On IE7 it expands down but the rest of the content below disappears, why is this happening.

Tried various ie7 specific CSS hacks but can't figure it so I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my jQuery? Here is the section controlling the expanding section:

```
// close helps
$(".helpClose").click(function(){
$(".help").hide('slow');
$(".helpTrigger").removeClass('hover')
});

// help Project
$(".helpTrigger").click(function(){    
    if (location.hash == '#Project') {
    $("#helpProject").slideToggle();
    return false;
    }
    if (location.hash == '#Rainfall') {
    $("#helpRainfall").slideToggle();
    return false;
    }
    if (location.hash == '#Drainage') {
    $("#helpDrainage").slideToggle();
    return false;
    }
    if (location.hash == '#Evaluate') {
    $("#helpEvaluate").slideToggle();
    return false;
    }
    if (location.hash == '#Attenuation') {
    $("#helpAttenuation").slideToggle();
    return false;
    }
});
```

The full jQuery script I'm using to control everything (which is called at the bottom of the HTML) is [here](http://acodesign.co.uk/enter/staging/bf_html_master/js/loader.js):

Answer (score 0):

@First issue: Already tried $(document).ready()? that should may help to show first container content if your DOM is ready.

@Second Issue: Firstly, ive seen a missing semicolon after $(".helpTrigger").removeClass('hover')
ie is very intolerant at javascript ...

Comment: Hi YeppThat'sMe, tried those but to no avail. Also ran the entire loader.js (that the code above is an excerpt of) through jslint but it doesn't seem to turn up anything relevant. Admittedly, I don't know what the majority of what jslint brings up means but it mainly seems to be spacing issues rather than actual malformed code.